# Need a Qt workaround for casting one base to the other

Tags: c++, qt, multiple-inheritance, dynamic-cast

Consider the following:

```
class MyInterface { /* ... */ }; // has virtual methods and all

class MyToolButton : public QToolButton, public MyInterface { /* ... */ };

class MyRadioButton : public QRadioButton, public MyInterface { /* ... */ };

class MyFrame : public QFrame { /* ... */ };

void MyFrame::doesNotWork()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < layout()->count(); ++i)
    {
        QLayoutItem *item = layout()->itemAt(i); // can be either MyToolButton or MyRadioButton
        Q_ASSERT(item); // passes
        MyInterface *interface = dynamic_cast<MyInterface*>(item);
        Q_ASSERT(interface); // TRIGGERS
    }
}
```

Is there some creative Qt way to get a pointer to `MyInterface` here? `QLayoutItem` does not inherit from `QObject`, which is sort of sad.

Comment: Not a Qt developer here, but a`QRadioButton` is a `QObject`.  Is it a `QLayoutItem`?  Tried calling `widget` on the layout item and then casting?

Comment: @Yakk Ha! Calling `widget()` and casting it from `QWidget` indeed solves it. Thanks, man.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QLayoutItems are not the widgets; they are the abstraction if how a widget (or something else) is positioned.  To get the widget, call `widget()` on the layout item.  Then dynamic_cast that.